# Tanstack react-table cannot return tsx from cell function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, tanstack

just testing Tanstack react-table lib with react + Typescript, and it seams that I can't return tsx/jsx from cell function of ColumnDef:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out that my file was with extension .ts and not .tsx, so changing from .ts to .tsx solved problem.

Answer (score -1):

Identify the difference between JSX and JS (brackets).

```
cell: ({ getValue }) => <div>{getValue()}</div>
```

Comment: It is not that my friend...even <div></div> throws error